# How do i wire light switch up in bedroom?

Tags: light-fixture

My 4 wall plug ins read open neutral, the ceiling light switch has been removed all that is left in box is 1 whit 1 black and 1 bare copper wire how to fix light switch? Hu.1 of the white wires may have fallen in the wall, is that possible.

Comment: Who removed the switch and how was it wired before?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, we'll need more info before we have any chance of helping you. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Picture of the lighting j-box would go a long way. Assuming you lost neutral when working on light, probable scenario is you broke the neutral at the light. The white at the switch is not a neutral, it is likely the hot, connected to blacks at the light. All the other whites in the lighting box need to be connected together, but post pic before you change anything.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the light and switch boxes please?